# Pivot Longer with Multiple Variables at Once

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like the first image and I want to make it look like the second image. I can pivot_longer by either age or speed, but not both at the same
[top is original, bottom is what I want to pivot to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQRyP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` with `names_sep`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = -ID, names_sep="_", names_to = c(".value", "grp"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#     ID grp     age speed
#  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 t1       10   100
#2     1 t2       11   300
#3     2 t1       11   500
#4     2 t2       12   100
#5     3 t1       10   200
#6     3 t2       11   300
#7     4 t1       12   100
#8     4 t2       13   400
```

---

If the column names have multiple `_`, then we can use a regex lookaround

```
names(df1) <- c("ID", "age_T1", "age_T2", "speed_total_T1", "speed_total_T2")
pivot_longer(df1, cols = -ID, names_sep="_(?=T)", names_to = c(".value", "grp"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#     ID grp     age speed_total
#  <int> <chr> <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     1 T1       10         100
#2     1 T2       11         300
#3     2 T1       11         500
#4     2 T2       12         100
#5     3 T1       10         200
#6     3 T2       11         300
#7     4 T1       12         100
#8     4 T2       13         400
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, age_t1 = c(10, 11, 10, 12), age_t2 = c(11, 
12, 11, 13), speed_t1 = c(100, 500, 200, 100), speed_t2 = c(300, 
100, 300, 400)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, that doesn't turn the first image in the question above into the second image. Instead is only keeps "T1" to "T4" as column names

Comment: @Ben Regarding the 'T1' to "T4", that was my earlier code, which i updated

Comment: oh I'm sorry the speed variable is actually titled speed_total_T1 through T4

Comment: Yes, my apologies. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Ben Based on the example I showed, would this be the correct column names `c("ID", "age_T1", "age_T2", "speed_total_T1", "speed_total_T2")`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much